# Как скрыть not found errors в логах nginx?

Tags: nginx

```
location = /favicon.ico {
    return 204;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}
```

Имеется вот так кусок в nginx конфиге, хочу добавить ещё пару файлов, для которых надо отключить логирование, но не хочу создать отдельную секцию. Как сюда можно вписать сразу несколько?

Comment: Никак. Пишите отдельные секции. Кстати, log_not_found тут лишний

Comment: @AlexeyTen, окей, не лишний, у меня на API страницах нет фавикона, и чтобы не мусорить логи, я его вписал, или return 204 уже делает, то что я хочу?

Comment: Можно, конечно, регулярками, но это будет бессмысленный обогрев воздуха. Сотню простых location nginx обработает быстрее и эффективнее одной регулярки

Comment: Именно. Return 204 это уже «найдено»

Answer (score 0):

Можно через или сделать

Примерно так

```
location ~ /(favicon.ico|file1.txt|file2.txt) {
  return 204;
  access_log off;
  log_not_found off;
}
```

Comment: Пробовал, работает в таком случае только для последнего указанного.

Comment: Поправил ответ, там последний слеш не нужен. Просто ```location ~ /(favicon.ico|file1.txt|file2.txt) {```